# Feline hyperesthesia

Tags: cats, health, diseases

My 8 year old cat has just been diagnosed with feline hyperesthesia. Out of the blue she began attacking her tail. She’s wearing a cone and taking 4 daily medications. Is it manageable? Or am I going to have to put her down? She’s miserable or she’s passed out. Tonight I took her cone off to let her clean after she eat and she licked and chewed her foot until it bled. I don’t know what to do and I’m heartbroken.

Comment: Can you tell us some more about when the symptoms set on or when they got so severe? Did you change anything in your home at that time? Like different food, new food/water bowl, different litter, new furniture (not only the cat's, but your's too), Different cleaning products, air refresheners? Did you have your cat groomed or shaved? Is there anything that stressed her like having fleas or mites, moving to a different home or having a new addition to the family (either human or animal)? Please [edit] your question and add anything that comes to your mind.

Comment: Maybe get a second opinion? I'm not a vet, but I'm pretty sure feline hyperesthesia is diagnosed in the absence of the vet being able to find other illnesses, and it seems a little odd to me for it to just suddenly start happening (or become suddenly way worse) after 8 years, when first onset is normally when the cat reaches maturity. If it really is hyperesthesia though, my cat has some specific triggers -- cooking spicey things, and getting particularly hungry seem to set him off consistently.

Comment: We did just move in May. This is a much quieter apartment. She was sleeping, sprawling in the sunny spots. No new people or furniture, no change in diet or litter. She’s on: Phenobarbital, gabapentin, xanex and her regular appoquel and revolution. Attacks started 60 days ago.
Her vet wanted to amputate her tail, I took her to a cat hospital who noticed her skin rippling. Dr said it was part of the hyperesthesia. 
Today, when I take the cone off so she can groom and eat, one hour am/pm she has started attacking her feet It’s getting worse in spite of the medication

Comment: It sounds strange to me too that your cat is diagnosed with hyperesthesia at this age. Has she not had any symptoms before? If not, then it seems unlikely to me. But I'm not a vet, so I could be wrong. Either way, that's quite a list of medications you've got her on. Have you or your vet considered that it might be an interaction effect of the medicines? Other options I would consider are food allergies that cause severe itching (these can develop and worsen over time, so seems a better fit) or even mites/fleas.

Comment: Also: the fact that your vet suggested amputation within 60 days has me worried. That seems like a last resort. And how would it help if she also attacks her feet? I would definitely seek out a second opinion.